# Getting int to UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing an Android application that brute-forces an MD5 sum created from an `int`.

**The brute forcing part works fine. (I can `sysout` the final value and it's correct.)**

I'm having problems getting the output value onto an alert dialog. Logcat says: `Attempting to initialize hardware acceleration outside of the main thread, aborting`

It's aborting on the last statement in my code, the one that actually shows the alert dialog;

```
builder.show();
```

Here's my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String passwordToHash;
    String result;
    boolean goodPIN = false;
    boolean startbruteforce = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //My stuff

    public void doIt(View v) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.crack);

        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTextArea);
        final EditText output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.outputTextArea);

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Working on it!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(r2.isChecked())
        {
            if(input.getText().toString().length() > 4)
            {
                goodPIN = false;
                output.setText("");
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle ("Uuuuuuhh....");
                builder.setMessage("Hash not calculated because that PIN would take too long to brute force :(");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yeah, whatever...", null);
                builder.show();
            }
            else
            {
                goodPIN = true;
            }

            if(goodPIN)
            {
                View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }

                Toast.makeText(this, "Calculated MD5!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                passwordToHash = input.getText().toString();

                MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

                byte[] inputBytes = passwordToHash.getBytes("UTF-8");

                byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(inputBytes);

                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.length; i++)
                {
                    stringBuffer.append(Integer.toString((hashBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                            .substring(1));
                }

                result = stringBuffer.toString();

                output.setText(result);
            }
        }


        else if(r1.isChecked())
        {
            View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

            final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Working on it!", "Brute-forcing. Please wait...", true);
            double starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            final Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    String crackedPassword = "Hello";
                    String crackedPasswordHash = "a262";
                    int pinsTested = 1000;
                    int crackedPasswordInt = 1000;
                    String passwordToCrack;

                    //Get the password to crack
                    passwordToCrack = input.getText().toString();

                    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    while (!crackedPasswordHash.equals(passwordToCrack))
                    {
                        pinsTested++;
                        crackedPasswordInt++;
                        crackedPassword = Integer.toString(crackedPasswordInt);

                        MessageDigest digest = null;
                        try
                        {
                            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                        }
                        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[0];
                        try
                        {
                            inputBytes = crackedPassword.getBytes("UTF-8");
                        }
                        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(inputBytes);

                        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.length; i++)
                        {
                            stringBuffer.append(Integer.toString((hashBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                                    .substring(1));
                        }

                        crackedPasswordHash = stringBuffer.toString();

                        //System.out.println(pinsTested + " PINs tested");
                        //System.out.println("Hash of: " + pinsTested + " is: " + crackedPasswordHash);
                    }
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;

                    System.out.println("Done! " + pinsTested);

                    updateUI(pinsTested);

                    //runOnUiThread(pinsTested);
                }
            };

            Thread animation = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    thread.start();
                }
            };

            animation.start();

        }
    }

    public void updateUI(final int pass) {

        Looper.prepare();
        final Handler myHandler = new Handler();
            (new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            test(pass);
                        }
                    });
                }
        })).start();
    }

    public void test(int pass)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle ("Done!");
        builder.setMessage("PIN is: " + pass);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yeah, whatever...", null);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) says:to move data from a background thread to the UI thread, use a Handler that's running on the UI thread.
You create Handler in method updateUI ，but the updateUI is created in thread other than UI Thread,so you get the error.
You need to try like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
               case 1:
               test((int)msg.obj);
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateUI(final int pass) {
         Message msg = Message.obtain();
         msg.what=1;
         msg.obj = pass;
         mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation,

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

So you are creating the handler in the "updateUI" method and that method is called from a thread other than the UI thread, in this case you need to declare your Handler as a member variable and initialize the Handler in the onCreate method.

[Handler](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit on how to do that? (My previous apps have just used the main thread, so I'm a noob to this multithreading thing)

Comment: [Handler example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/) here is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

you can do everything u want in inside run method:
but its not very safe!

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
```